# Dynamically Add RegularExpressionValidator C#

Tags: c#, reg-expressionvalidator

I have this `FileUpload` control that automatically adds a `FileUpload` Control.  But I need to have it also create an `RegularExpressionValidator`.  Not sure how I can do this.

Any ideas?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
function AddFileUpload() {
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
 '" type="file" />' +
  '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
  'value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
    counter++;
}
function RemoveFileUpload(div) {
    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}
</script>  


<div id="FileUploadContainer">
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> 

     <!--FileUpload Controls will be added here -->

</div>    
<br />

 <input id="Button1" onclick="AddFileUpload()" style="height: 27px; width: 150px;" tabindex="25" type="button" value="Add More Attachments" />

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
 ErrorMessage="Only .pdf, .jpg"
 ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Pp][Dd][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])$)">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try this way:

> 1. Always initiate Regular Expression Validator in the page along with the control.
> 2. Make the Regular Expression Validation disable through javascript and make the control's display to none if you don't need the control
>      presence in the UI.
> 3. Make the Regular Expression Validation enable through javascript and make the control's to be appeared if you need the control presence
>      in the UI.

Good Reference to read for this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx